# Delete an object by id in python?

Tags: python, object

If I get the id of an object,
how can I delete an object by it's id ?

Comment: How did you get the id?  You called `id(someObject)`, right?  You will also do `del someObject`.  How is it possible to have the id, but not the object?  Can you provide some context or code sample?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a good idea.  Try using the [weakref module](http://docs.python.org/library/weakref.html#example), which allows you to create weak references (analogous to symbolic links) to objects.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK objects are deleted by garbage collector in python. You can't force a delete yourself.

Comment: Not strictly true; that's what the `del` keyword is for.

Comment: No, that's not deleting object, but deleting a variable. Totally different thing.

Comment: Delete the variable.  The reference count goes to zero.  The object can be removed, then, also.

Comment: You don't have to wait for the next cycle of garbage collector?

Comment: You don't delete a variable in Python, you delete a name aka reference to an object; Python doesn't have variables in the sense of other programming languages. In CPython, an objects gets deleted if its reference count reaches zero unless it's part of a cycle, so its deletion becomes responsibility of the garbage collector.

Answer (score 0):

The id refers to a memory address. You "can't" delete (or free) a memory address, only its references, with the *del* statement

Answer (score -2):

You can delete objects by calling del() on them.
But AFAIK id won't help in that.